# Relation between Ramanujan Theta Function and Jacobi Theta Function

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms, q-series

In the theory of $q-$series,
we have Ramanujan Theta function
\begin{align}\label{rama-theta}
        f(a,b):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}
        a^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}b^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}
        ,\qquad |ab|<1.
\end{align}
And we also have Jacobi Theta function in complex analysis defined by
\begin{align}
          \Theta(z|\tau)=
          \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\pi i n^2 \tau}e^{2\pi i n z}.
\end{align}
We can also write it as
\begin{align}
          \Theta(z|\tau)=
          \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^2}\eta^n,
        \end{align}
where $\eta=e^{2\pi i z}$ and $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}.$

In wiki, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function,
he says "…… the Ramanujan theta function generalizes the form of the Jacobi theta functions……".

I cannot understand why it can be regarded as a generalization.
In my opinion，
Jacobi triple product have the following two expression
\begin{align}
\Theta(z|\tau)=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-e^{2\pi m i\tau})\left[1+e^{(2m-1)\pi i \tau+2\pi i z}\right]\left[1+e^{(2m-1)\pi i \tau-2\pi i z}\right].
\end{align}
But in the notation of Ramanujan,
we have
\begin{align}
          f(a,b)=(-a;ab)_\infty(-b;ab)(ab;ab)_\infty.
\end{align}
This is more beautiful.

However,
I still don't know what's the relation between the two kinds of "Theta function".
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that the theta functions of Ramanujan and Jacobi are equivalent if we have $$ab=e^{2\pi i\tau}, a/b=e^{4\pi i z} $$ or $$a=e^{\pi i\tau+2\pi i z}, b=e^{\pi i\tau-2\pi i z} $$ Thus given any complex numbers $a, b$ with $|ab|<1$ gives us values of $\tau, z$ such that $\tau$ has positive imaginary part. The equations given above on the other hand express $a, b$ in terms of $\tau, z$.